# Simple tensorial calculation

Tags: tensor-calculus

when proving that a gradient of a vector is not a tensor, we do the following

$$
\partial^{'}_{\nu}A^{'\mu} = \frac{\partial A^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{'\nu}}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'\nu}} (\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha})=\frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{'\nu}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\beta}}(\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha})=\frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{'\nu}} \frac{\partial^2 x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\beta} \partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha}+\frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{'\nu}} \frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}(\partial_\beta A^{\alpha})
$$

However, why the following steps are wrong? When in the 2nd step we change the variable in respect to which we differentiate ($ x^{'\nu} \rightarrow x^{\beta} $), why can't we just continue and differentiate with respect to the initial variable $x^{'\nu}$

$$
\partial^{'}_{\nu}A^{'\mu} = \frac{\partial A^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{'\nu}}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'\nu}} (\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha})=( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}})A^{\alpha}+\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'\nu}}A^{\alpha}   = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{'\nu}})A^{\alpha}+\frac{\partial x^{'\mu}}{\partial x^{'\nu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha} = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\delta^{'\mu}_{\nu})A^{\alpha}+\delta^{'\mu}_{\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha}= 0\cdot A^{\alpha}+\delta^{'\mu}_{\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}A^{\alpha}
$$

I fully understand that the 2nd approach is wrong, but could anyone say in which step is the mistake made?

Thanks!

Comment: Well first $\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\nu} \neq \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x'^\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$ (equality 4, second term). You can (usually) switch partial derivatives, but what you have here is basically $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ which is a differential operator and is in  general not equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.